# Що за слово неповносправний?

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія

В одному з українських інтернет-видань є [стаття](https://espreso.tv/news/2015/12/03/poroshenko_proty_sliv_quotnepovnospravnyyquot_i_quotinvalidquot) з назвою "Порошенко проти слів "неповносправний" і "інвалід"". У тлумачному словнику Української мови в 11т. слово *неповносправний* відсутнє. За морфологічним складом також залишається незрозумілим, що за неповні справи у людини можуть бути. То що це за прикметник, звідки він узявся?

Comment: Теж не зрозумів, але у вікісловнику слово має тлумачення: https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: [Є версія](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t2958.html) що це калька з польської - [niepełnosprawny](https://sjp.pwn.pl/sjp/;2489264) «nieosiągający pełnej sprawności fizycznej lub psychicznej».

Comment: @Artemix, схоже на те, словотвір виглядає неприроднім для української мови.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Це слово можна знайти у [Вікісловнику](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), де воно означає "той, що не справляється сам, а потребує сторонньої допомоги". І так, як було зазначено в коментарях, воно справді схоже на [польське слово](https://sjp.pwn.pl/sjp/;2489264). Також, дане питання було обговорено на цьому [форумі](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t2958.html), де було вказано, що "...нічого протизаконного немає у слові неповносправний. Неповносправний - той, хто не в змозі самостійно щось справляти: виконувати, здійснювати. І неповносправний звучить більш соціально незалежно та повноцінно, аніж людина-інвалід (чи того ліпше - каліка)". Також там було зазначено, що це слово не порушує норм українського словотвору, тому воно теоретично воно можливе.

Також про те, що це слово можна і навіть потрібно використовувати ми можемо знайти у цій [статті](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) із Вікіпедії.